# Seamless desktop startup

Tags: linux, desktop, xfce, splash

I use Xfce + Compiz + Emerald. When the system starts up I see:

- Xfce starting up (desktop background, desktop icons, taskbar)
- Compiz startup (the whole screen goes black and everything rebuilt)
- Session restore (starting the applications I used when I shut the system down)

What I would like to see is a kind of a "splash screen" but I would prefer the whole screen filled with a single color (don't really need any image) and when **everything** is finished loading this (always-on-top style) window should fade out in front of my desktop ready to use.

So I need a decent splash screen. The default Xfce splash is blinking a few times, then when the session restore happens the windows appear over the splash. It also does not fade out just simply disappears. - I'm looking for one which was designed to be solid (to hide the ugly frames during startup) rather than customizable.